# Как увеличить размер диска за счет другого без потери данных?

Tags: windows, сервер

Здравствуйте.
Кто-нибудь знает, как в **Windows Server 2008**  выдрать место из одного диска и поместить его в другой **БЕЗ ПОТЕРИ ДАННЫХ**.
Т.е. на диске "C" катастрофически не хватает места, надо его добавить из другого диска (например E) без потери данных.
Partition Magic говорит, что в серверной винде он не хочет работать.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использование стороннего софта типа Acronis, Paragon или PartitionMagic для управления разделами.

> Partition Magic говорит, что в серверной винде он не хочет работать.

1. Скачать серверную версию PM.
2. Переделать серверную винду в десктопную (напр., с помощью TweakNT), но это опаснее, чем использование менеджеров разделов.

> А уже существующую директорию как ссылку на другой диск сделать не получается.

Действительно, можно воспользоваться reparse point. Для этого переносим Ваш каталог на другой раздел. Остается на диске C: пустой каталог C:blablablablablabla, а теперь в него можно подмонтировать тот раздел, где у Вас файлы
Плюс можно воспользоваться такой чудесной штукой как symlink (правда, в винде они работают кривовато), если не устраивает положение данных на диске, но передвигать их по структуре каталогов не хочется.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузите liveCD Акрониса или партишна и загрузитесь с него, в этом случае будет все равно какая винда стоит.

Comment: Единственное что ОООЧЕНЬ плохо - это то, что надо перезагружать сервер, что делать по определению нельзя во время рабочего дня.

Comment: Вот если бы был способ, чтобы можно было все сделать БЕЗ перезагрузки сервера .....

Answer (score 1):

Можно замаунтить раздел как директорию ([вот пример](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-xp/how-to-mount-an-external-drive-partititon-as-directory-in-xp/)), причем не используя сторонний софт.

Comment: Счас попробую...

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, попробовал сделать так, и как все должно работать?

Comment: Все должно работать так:
Есть диск С(20гб) и Е(40гб). Если примаунтить диск Е по адресу C:\\data\. То заполнив диск С на 20 гб, в папку data можно положить еще 40гб, так как физически файлы будут на E.

Comment: А нет, так не подходит. Мне надо просто расширить место для постоянно увеличивающейся БД, ну и для программных файлов. А уже существующую директорию как ссылку на другой диск сделать не получается.
Все равно спасибо за ответ) Буду пробовать liveCD Акрониса или партишна...

Comment: А кто вам мешает в таком случае скопировать файлы на новый диск, а в папку где были эти файлы подмонтировать новый диск? Естественно как и везде понадобится ребут сервера, иначе, к сожалению, никак.
Да и кто держит файлы базы на диске с операционкой? Это вы зряяя!

Answer (score 0):

После изменения структуры разделов, все равно потребуется ребут

Comment: Ну и вообще сомнительно чтобы Windows позволил перенарезать диск с собственным системным разделом на разделы

Answer (score 0):

Можете подмонтировать диск как папку, но это временное решение.
Забекапьте диск или важные данные с него куда нибудь, а потом переразметьте. Если вы говорите о двух HDD, то разметьте как вам надо второй диск и скопируйте данные в соответствующие разделы акронисом или гостом.